# Cannot Install Ssh2 on centos 7 with php version 5.6

Tags: php, ssh, centos7, pecl, libssh2

I'm trying to install Ssh2 on centos7 with php version 5.6.40 but i get this error :

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl
> channel-update pecl.php.net" to update pecl/ssh2 requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.40
>
> No valid packages found
>
> install failed

I know that i need to update the php version in order for the ssh2 package to work but the application installed on the server requires php 5.6 to function correctly.

PS: i have another centos7 server running with the same config and ssh2 is already installed and working perfectly on it so i tried to copy the whole ssh2 directory to the new server but it didn't work.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You appear to have two contradictory requirements - "keep PHP 5.6", and "upgrade PHP". It's not clear how you can achieve your apparent objective on that basis.

Comment: Possibly your existing server had an earlier version of ssh2 on it, so at a guess maybe you need to see if you can get that version onto your other machine, rather than whatever it's trying to download. It's unclear precisely what installation procedure you are following, as you didn't show us what commands/steps you had run in order to get the warning.

Comment: P.S. It's a **long** time past the time when this application should have been updated to run on a supported, maintained, secure version of PHP. Ultimately, running out of date software when you shouldn't, is the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @ADyson I don't want to upgrade php, i need to keep the 5.6 version and have ssh2 installed alongside with it. i just want a version of ssh2 that will work with php 5.6.

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much for your interest i really appreciate the help.
The commands i ran were :
wget https://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.9.0.tar.gz
yum -y install libssh2-1.8.0-4.el7.x86_64 libssh2-devel-1.8.0-4.el7.x86_64|tee -a /tmp/install_log

Comment: Why did you download 1.9 but then try to install 1.8? What version of ssh is installed on the server where you say it's working? P.S. Rather than burying info down here in the comments (which are not meant to turn into a long discussion) please make the info far more visible by putting it into your question - you can [edit] it whenever you like. Thanks.

Comment: `I don't want to upgrade php`...regardless of whether you want to, it's a long time since that version was supported or updated, and it may contain unpatched vulnerabilities, lacks features, etc etc etc. You are being left behind technology-wise, and also running a big security and reputational risk by hosting application software on seriously out-of-date platforms. If this is anything other than a hobby platform, that should be regarded as a significant operational business risk by whoever owns and operates these servers, and an upgrade plan should have been put in place years ago.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php and https://www.php.net/eol.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.